# Cómo agregar un campo nuevo a una estructura ya declarada (estructura dinámica)

Tags: go, gorm

Estoy creando un servidor web sencillo con **fiber** y **gorm** *(aún me hace falta mucho para entender bien gorm)*.

Tengo un método que realiza una búsqueda en mi db, el cual obtiene todos los **pedidos** registrados, luego recorro dichos pedidos, y por cada **pedido** obtengo los **productos** del **pedido**, pero lo que me sucede es que no he podido agregarle los **productos** obtenidos a mi **pedido** para poder armar el JSON de respuesta de tal forma que quede así:

```
pedidos: [
  {
     nombre: "asd",
     fecha: "sd",
     productos: [
      { nombre: "asdasd", "precio": 123 },
      { nombre: "popod", "precio": 456 } 
     ]
  }
]
```

**Método que recupera los pedidos del sistema**

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func GetPedidos(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    db := database.DB
    queryProductos := fmt.Sprintf(`select * from "Pedido_Detalle" pd, "Producto" p where p."Id" = pd."Producto_Id" and pd."Pedido_Id" = ?`)
    var (
        pedidos       []model.Pedido
        productos     []model.Producto
        rows          *sql.Rows
        errorConsulta error
        producto      model.Producto
    )
    db.Table("Pedido").Find(&pedidos)
    respuestaPedidos := make([]model.Pedido, len(pedidos))

    for _, pedido := range pedidos {
        rows, errorConsulta = db.Raw(queryProductos, pedido.Id).Rows()

        if errorConsulta != nil {
            fmt.Println("[error querySQL]", errorConsulta)
            continue
        }

        for rows.Next() {
            db.ScanRows(rows, &producto)
            productos = append(productos, producto)
        }
        // pedido.Productos = productos
        respuestaPedidos = append(respuestaPedidos, pedido)
    }
    return c.Status(fiber.StatusOK).JSON(
        fiber.Map{
            "data":    pedidos,
            "items":   len(pedidos),
            "status":  fiber.StatusOK,
            "success": true,
        },
    )
}
```

Ya intenté agregando el tipo **Producto** en la propiedad **Productos** de mi modelo **Pedido** pero cuando ejecuto la consulta:

```
db.Table("Pedido").Find(&pedidos)
```

me arroja un error diciendo que no hay una **FK** entre mi modelo **Pedido** y mi modelo **Producto** y por tal razón la consulta falla.

**Pedido model**

```
package model

type Pedido struct {
    Id                  int         `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Productos           []*Producto `json:"productos,omitempty"`
    Usuario_Id          uint        `gorm:"not null" json:"usuarioId"`
    Estado_Pedido       uint        `json:"estadoPedido"`
    Fecha_Estado_Pedido string      `json:"fechaEstadoPedido"`
    Estado_Pago_Id      int         `json:"estadoPagoId"`
    Fecha_Estado_Pago   string      `json:"fechaEstadoPago"`
    Fecha_Estimada      string      `json:"fechaEstimada"`
    Ubicacion_Id        uint        `gorm:"not null" json:"ubicacionId"`
    Direccion_Entrega   string      `json:"direccionEntrega"`
    Vlr_Envio           float32     `gorm:"not null" json:"valorEnvio"`
    Vlr_Descuento       float32     `gorm:"not null" json:"valorDescuento"`
    Vlr_Impuesto        float32     `gorm:"not null" json:"valorImpuesto"`
    Vlr_Total           float32     `gorm:"not null" json:"valorTotal"`
    Contacto_Entrega    string      `gorm:"not null" json:"contactoEntrega"`
    Telefono_Contacto   string      `gorm:"not null" json:"telefonoContacto"`
    Tipo_Pago           uint        `gorm:"not null" json:"tipoPago"`
    Ruta_Pago           string      `json:"rutaPago"`
    Info_Pago           string      `json:"infoPago"`
    Observaciones       string      `json:"observaciones"`
    Fecha_Creacion      string      `gorm:"not null" json:"fechaCreacion"`
}
```

**Producto model**

```
package model

import (
    "time"
)

type Producto struct {
    Id                    int       `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`
    Proveedor_id          string    `gorm:"not null" json:"provedorId"`
    Nombre                string    `gorm:"not null" json:"nombre"`
    Presentacion          string    `gorm:"not null" json:"presentacion"`
    Descripcion           string    `gorm:"not null" json:"descripcion"`
    Cantidad              string    `gorm:"not null" json:"cantidad"`
    Vlr_Unit              string    `gorm:"not null" json:"valorUnit"`
    Prc_Impuesto          string    `gorm:"not null" json:"precioImpuesto"`
    Prc_Descuento         string    `gorm:"not null" json:"precioDescuento"`
    Es_Destacado          bool      `gorm:"not null" json:"esDestacado"`
    Tipo_Unidad           uint      `gorm:"not null" json:"tipoUnidad"`
    Peso_Kg               float32   `gorm:"not null" json:"pesoKg"`
    Activo                bool      `gorm:"not null" json:"activo"`
    Fecha_Creacion        time.Time `gorm:"not null" json:"fechaCreacion"`
    Categoria_Producto_Id uint      `json:"categoriaProductoId"`
    Ruta_Ficha_Tecnica    string    `json:"rutaFichaTecnica"`
    Fecha_Modificacion    time.Time `json:"fechaModificacion"`
}
```

La forma en que relaciono mis datos es con una tabla intermedia, en esta guardo todos los **productos** de un **pedido**.

[image: MER de la base de datos]

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo cual es la pregunta.. El problema es:

1- ¿Que al consultar los `Pedidos` en la bd no eres capaz de leer el atributo `Productos` y la información **si** está en la bd?

2- ¿O qué no eres capaz de insertar un `Pedido` que tenga varios `Producto` en la bd?

En cualquier caso ¿te has leído la documentación [Has Many](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html)? ¿por qué lo defines como un *, en vez de `Productos []Producto` ?

La clave foránea por defecto que usa GORM es:

> To define a has many relationship, a foreign key must exist. The
> default foreign key’s name is the owner’s type name plus the name of
> its primary key field

en tu caso `PedidoId`